# Unable to read char array using cin.getline

Tags: c++, string, class, char, cin

We were asked to create a class which did the following:

1. Input **int ecode**, **char ename** and **basicpay**
2. Now in class, we had to calculate **net_pay = basicpay*11/10**
3. Lastly, we had to output ecode, ename and net_pay.

The question stated that net_pay variable cannot be created, its value only has to be used for output, and that value had to be calculated using a separate member function **calc**

Here is my code:

```
// Class employee

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

class emp {
    int ecode;
    char ename[20];
    float basic_pay;

    public:
        void input() {
            cin >> ecode;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline( ename, 20);  // <-- PROBLEM HERE
            cin >> basic_pay;
        }
        float calc( float x) {
            return x+x/10;
        }
        void output() {
            cout << "\n Emp. code: " << ecode;
            cout << "\n Emp. name: " << ename;
            cout << "\n Emp. basic pay: " << basic_pay;
            cout << "\n Emp. net pay: " << calc( basic_pay);
        }
};

int main() {
    emp e1;
    cout << "Enter details of employee:\n";
    e1.input();
    cout << "\nUpdated Profile:\n";
    e1.output();
    return 0;
}
```

### Error

I am frustrated from past hour about this problem with `cin.getline`.

### String size < 20

The code is working fine for input string size less than 20, so I don't need cin.ignore(), and if I use it, `cin.ignore` is removing a first digit of `basic_pay`:

**See images:** Both are for small string input. Second one is with `cin.ignore()`

[image]

Notice below: Basic_pay was 1100, but it ignored `1`.

[image]

### String size > 20

If I input a string with char number greater than 20, then the overflowing char goes to float, and creates error. So to counter this, I need a cin.ignore(), but even that is not working!

[image]

### Question

I am in a dilemma. For one string size, `cin.ignore()` is problamatic, but for other it has no effect. What to use, what not to use? Both are creating mutual conflict. Help me please!

Comment: Use the [`std::string` version of `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) - no more worries about the name length!

Comment: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), not `char[]`. [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), not `std::iostream::getline()`. Text, not screenshots. Please. (Why aren't your instructors teaching you this?)

Comment: @BoBTFish I used string and getline and it worked fine. Basically, I use standard c++ everywhere. But our teacher is fore towards old Turbo C++ type C++, And she needs C type code. I behave in school as if std::string does not exist. We are made to write non-standard code, so i have no other option!

Comment: @samjoe I know this is very common practice, but I can't imagine how your school (and others) believe they are actually preparing you for the workplace by teaching you style and techniques that are 20+ years out of date.

Comment: @samjoe Can you, and maybe a group of other students, complain to the head of department, or preferably someone higher outside of the department? They are actively doing you more harm than not learning C++ at all. +1 for trying to learn it properly outside of class though.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.getline(name, 20)` can only get 19 characters (one is reserved for the '\0'), therefore if someone inputs 20 or more, then `cin.getline(name, 20)` will fail, and the next `cin >> basic_pay` will fail too since the stream error flags are still set, you need to clear them with `cin.clear()`.

Fix:

```
    #include <limits> // for numeric_limits

    if (!cin.getline(ename, 20))  // <-- PROBLEM HERE
    {
        std::cout << "Name too long, trimmed to: " << ename << std::endl;

        // clear the stream error flags and ignore rest of the line
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }

    // now this line will not fail
    cin >> basic_pay;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/OZ5eXT)